# How to pass JOB parameters using Jenkins HTTP POST plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to pass the Build Name and the BUILD ID to the REST API using Jenkins HTTP POST plugin

how to pass the parameters to it?

I am passing:

http://localhost:55223/api/Demo?BuildName=${JOB_NAME}&BuildID=${BUILD_ID}

I am receiving an error

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Plugin does not expand environment variables, as evidenced by it's [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-post-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/httppost/HttpPostPublisher.java). As the plugin has not been updated in 2 years, I don't think there's any chance of the developer adding this anytime soon. If you are still wanting to use the plugin, you could make the changes changes necessary to expand the environment variables and then build it from source. For that, I would recommend looking at the Jenkins classes [`hudson.EnvVars`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/EnvVars.html) and  [`hudson.model.Run`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html). More specifically, the Run method [`getEnvironment(TaskListener listener)`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html#getEnvironment-hudson.model.TaskListener-) and the EnvVars method [`expand(String s)`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/EnvVars.html#expand-java.lang.String-).